# Best-Prectice Check logged in User Spring-Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I came up with a Question regarding Spring, while implementing a project:

I got a few Roles (USER, ADMIN, ADVANCED_USER), but sometimes I need to check, if a specific resource is requested by a user, if the user is part of a specific Entity. I check that at the moment the following:

```java
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
User loggedIn = userRepository.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
if(allowedIds.contains(user.getId()) ... access allowed
else ... access denied, exception
```

Is there a smarter way to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper implementation to the Auth, and put it into the security context on login. There you can hold data which you needed over process the request. After that, you get the enriched user object from the securitycontext.